# Split text with '\r\n'

Tags: c#, string, split

I was following this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And I came up with this code:

```
string FileName = "C:\\test.txt";

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.Default))
{
    string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
    string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    string[] lines = text.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Here is the sample text:

```
somet interesting text\n
some text that should be in the same line\r\n
some text should be in another line
```

Here is the output:

```
somet interesting text\r\n
some text that should be in the same line\r\n
some text should be in another line\r\n
```

But what I want is this:

```
somet interesting textsome text that should be in the same line\r\n
some text should be in another line\r\n
```

I think I should get this result but somehow I am missing something...

Comment: Why don't you use `File.ReadAllLines` or `File.ReadLines`?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` will add the newline automatically after each string in your array.  You want to either merge the lines together BEFORE your loop, or as one answer suggested, replace the `\n` before you `Split` the text.

Comment: I want to have line that specifically ends with `\r\n` not `\n` or `\r`.

Comment: The problem is not that you have `\r\n` and  `\n` at the end but that you're forgetting that the lines actually contain already line-breaks. So even if you remove them you have three lines in the file.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the first line of the output ends with `\r\n`?  Add this line and see if it's what you expect:  `Console.WriteLine("lines.Length={0}", lines.Length);`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The problem is not with the splitting but rather with the `WriteLine`. A `\n` in a string printed with `WriteLine` will produce an "extra" line.

Example

```
var text = 
  "somet interesting text\n" +
  "some text that should be in the same line\r\n" +
  "some text should be in another line";

string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
string[] lines = text.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine("Nr. Of items in list: " + lines.Length); // 2 lines
foreach (string s in lines)
{
   Console.WriteLine(s); //But will print 3 lines in total.
}
```

To fix the problem remove `\n` before you print the string.

```
Console.WriteLine(s.Replace("\n", ""));
```

Comment: Yes, `Console.WriteLine()` was translating `\n` into `\r\n`.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me.

```
using System.IO;

//  

    string readStr = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);          
    string[] read = readStr.Split(new char[] {'\r','\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is in your text file. It's probably already split into too many lines and when you read it, it "adds" additional `\r` and/or `\n` characters (as they exist in file). Check your what is read into `text` variable.

The code below (on a local variable with your text) works fine and splits into 2 lines:

```
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
string text = "somet interesting text\nsome text that should be in the same line\r\nsome text should be in another line";
string[] lines = text.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: But why should I add it?

Answer (score 6):

I took a more compact approach to split an input resulting from a text area into a list of string . You can use this if suits your purpose.

the problem is you cannot split by \r\n so i removed the \n beforehand and split only by \r

```
var serials = model.List.Replace("\n","").Split('\r').ToList<string>();
```

I like this approach because you can do it in just one line.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the file is easier with the static `File` class:

```
// First read all the text into a single string.
string text = File.ReadAllText(FileName);

// Then split the lines at "\r\n".   
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
string[] lines = text.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);

// Finally replace lonely '\r' and '\n' by  whitespaces in each line.
foreach (string s in lines) {
    Console.WriteLine(s.Replace('\r', ' ').Replace('\n', ' '));
}
```

Note: The text might also contain vertical tabulators `\v`. Those are used by Microsoft Word as manual linebreaks.

In order to catch any possible kind of breaks, you could use regex for the replacement

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"[\f\n\r\t\v]", " "));
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
string stringSeparators = "\r\n";
string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
string lines = text.Replace(stringSeparators, "");
lines = lines.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n");
Console.WriteLine(lines);
```

The first replace replaces the `\r\n` from the text file's new lines, and the second replaces the actual `\r\n` text that is converted to `\\r\\n` when the files is read. (When the file is read `\` becomes `\\`).

Answer (score 1):

**In Winform App(C#):**

```
static string strFilesLoc = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), @"..\..\")) + "Resources\\";
    public static string[] GetFontFamily()
            {
                var result = File.ReadAllText(strFilesLoc + "FontFamily.txt").Trim();
                string[] items = result.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                return items;
            }
```

**In-text file(FontFamily.txt):** 
Microsoft Sans Serif 
9 
true

Answer (score 0):

Following code gives intended results.

```cs
string text="some interesting text\nsome text that should be in the same line\r\nsome 
text should be in another line"
var results = text.Split(new[] {"\n","\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split only works with a single character and need single quotes like '|' or '\n' but \r\n is a string so it can't be used with Split. Use Regex this instead

```
string[] lines=Regex.Split(str, "\r\n");
```

Don't forget `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`