# How to write regular expression to match first occurrence of ending word

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove the line starting with balance carried forward from below text

Balance carried forward                    170,806.80       3,558.48     167,248.32 \r\n  `<some other text>`  \r\n

Resultant text should be

`<some other text>`  \r\n

I tried with `Regex.Replace(body, _regex, "",RegexOptions.Singleline)` using below regex, but it is matching the \r\n at end of the string and body is blank.

```
Balance carried forward.*[\r\n|\r|\n]
```

Comment: could you not use the [Split Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185009/split-text-with-r-n) there is a similar `SO` Posting

Comment: Split is not an option for me as my approach is more generic. There are bunch of regex's the string will go through.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to iterate through the string until you find the first `\r\n` instance and, using that index, do the appropriate operations? Not necessarily what you're looking for, but it could be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern instead:

```
^Balance carried forward[^\r\n]*(?:\r\n|\r|\n)
```

Explanation:

```
^ // match at the start of a line
Balance carried forward
[^\r\n]* // match anything that's not a newline
(?:\r\n|\r|\n) // finally, match a newline
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
^Balance carried forward.*?\R
```

where `\R` stands for any of `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`.

If `\R` is not recognize, use:

```
^Balance carried forward.*?[\r\n]+
```

Comment: For some reason \R is not getting recognized in C#