# Comparing strings that are split from .txt file not working Unity C#

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I am trying to code a dialogue system for our game and I ran into a really simple but annoying problem. I am splitting lines of text from a .txt file to an array of strings. The strings themselves work perfectly, but Comparing them doesn't work as it usually does.

The code below is a simplified cut of what I'm currently doing. It shows the syntaxes I'm using to cut the strings and how I compare them. is to split the text, get the next text by pressing enter and automatically run a piece of code if it encounters certain text ("-" in this case).

So the question is, does the Split function add something to the strings or does the comparing have to be done differently?

```
private string[]  _textLines;
private TextAsset _textFile;
private int       _currentLine;

private void PrepareText()
    {
        _textFile = _textLoader.GetTextAsset();

        _textLines = (_textFile.text.Split('\n'));

private void update() {

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Continue"))
        _currentLine += 1;

    if (_textLines[_currentLine].Equals("-"))                            
        DisableTextBox();
}
```

When I log the content of the specified array slot, it gives me only "-" as it should, still the code doesn't see it as equal.

The .txt file I'm using for this test looks like below. I just want to run the code when it encounters the 4th line.

```
This is the first line
second line
third line, break coming
-
More dialog here
-
```

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any invisible characters, eg a leftover `\r`? What is the length of the string stored in the array? You can avoid this by using a StringReader or StreamReader and ReadLine

Comment: The files may be split by `\r\n` comabination. Then you get lines like `-\r` which is, of course, not equal to the `-`. BTW: I would rather recommend to use function `File.ReadAllLines` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: *"the code doesn't see it as equal"* - you haven't prove (or demonstrate) that. Can you narrow problem to a simple [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can try? Maybe `DisableTextBox()` has problems?

Comment: Try to convert it to ASCII and see if it gives you 45(- sign) Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);

Comment: Instead of `\n` use `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you check that discussion : [Split text with '\r\n'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185009/split-text-with-r-n)

Splitting with '\n' will not "split" the \r, so all your values in your array have the "\r" at the end.

You have different solutions in the post I've mentioned just above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick tips! Like suggested in the comments, using the following code adds an invisible character to the string.

```
_textFile.text.Split('\n')
```

Instead of learning something new like using the StringReader as suggested in the comments (because I'm a dumb like that), I made a quick workaround by changing the comparison with string.Equals() to string.Contains() and it works perfectly (except for the invisible character that doesn't really do anything in my case)

```
private string[]  _textLines;
private TextAsset _textFile;
private int       _currentLine;

private void PrepareText()
    {
        _textFile = _textLoader.GetTextAsset();

        _textLines = (_textFile.text.Split('\n'));

private void update() {

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Continue"))
        _currentLine += 1;

    if (_textLines[_currentLine].Contains("(end)"))                           
        DisableTextBox();
}
```

And for my example .txt file the necessary changes naturally look like this:

```
This is the first line
second line
third line, break coming
(end)
More dialog here
(end)
```